# Sort words in lexicographic order in R

Tags: r

I have no idea how to sort words of string sets in lexicographic order.

```
text = c('aca aad aac bgh bst', 'vac rff okj vbf', 'cad acd ccs sdf')
```

to be

```
text
[1] 'aac aad aca bgh bst'
[2] 'rff okj vac vbf'
[3] 'acd cad ccs sdf'
```

Like `text` above, it is important to be sorted in aphabetical order not only by first character but also by every successive character

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(text, split=" "), function(i) paste(sort(i), collapse=" "))` will do the trick.

Comment: Wow it works well. Thanks!

Comment: total gem of a one-liner!